# Failed to set the specified COM apartment state ApartmentState.STA

Tags: c#, multithreading, com

I am calling a COM method from a class A

So to make thread Model of .Net same to Single Threaded Apartment

I am calling following line of code in class A’s constructor

```
Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

But I am getting

Invalid operation exception “Failed to set the specified COM apartment state”

What can I do to set current thread  to  Single Threaded Apartment

Comment: It must be done *before* the thread is started, it cannot be changed afterwards.  Nor is it reasonable at all to force a thread into STA in code that doesn't also implement the STA contract.  Which is highly untrivial, it must pump a message loop and never block.  Application.Run() required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the COM method on a new thread and set that thread's state instead:

```
Thread newThread = 
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(MethodToCallCOMMethod));
newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newThread.Start();
```